# .sqlite file no more available in documents folder - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

The sqlite file related to coredata is no more available in the documents directory.

Found it is present inside `/Library/Application Support`

How to search for that url in proper way?

Comment: NSPersistentContainer class was introduced in iOS 10, and Apple changed the default location to keep the persistent store. it is now in the Application Support directory -> Library. we can modify it by overriding the defaultDirectoryURL() method in the subclass of NSPersistentContainer

Answer (score 1):

Using XCode 10.2 and Swift 5

Do simply

```
let url = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
```